# How to insert data into bridge table or into two tables at the same time from form in jsp page

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have 3 table Student,Subject and Course.Course is the bridge table which contain PK,FK : student_id and subject_id.How to insert data into these 3 tables from a form in jsp page?

```
CREATE TABLE "CS245"."SUBJECT" 
   (    "SUBJECT_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SUBJECT_NAME" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "SUBJECT_PRICE" NUMBER, 
    "SUBJECT_LEVEL" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "SUBJECT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SUBJECT_ID")

CREATE TABLE "CS245"."STUDENT" 
   (    "STUDENT_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STUDENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "STUDENT_AGE" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "STUDENT_CONTACT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "STUDENT_PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "STUDENT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("STUDENT_ID")

CREATE TABLE "CS245"."COURSE" 
   (    "SUBJECT_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "STUDENT_ID" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "COURSE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SUBJECT_ID", "STUDENT_ID")
```

Comment: I don't see FK being defined for **COURSE** table. Also, what have you tried? Steps to insert data remain same, 1. get db connection 2. Create statement 3. Prepare query 4. Execute query  What challenges you facing?

Comment: Do you face any challenges if you try on these lines , [inserting data into database using a jsp](http://p2p.wrox.com/jsp-basics/27251-inserting-data-into-database-using-jsp.html)

Comment: I don't know how to insert data get from a form jsp  page into two table in database and how to if I want the data from the form to be inserted into bridge table

Comment: are you looking for end to end guide? link that I pasted above has useful info to get started with.

Comment: The basic insert,update delete from a table have worked so far but i just don't know about join table no matter how much i have searched and read through online.

Comment: You first add foreign key for table COURSE and edit updated table schema in question. You can also use ON UPDATE & ON DELETE clauses while adding foreign key constraint to COURSE table.